# How to ignore brackets in file names when splitting and renaming?

Tags: powershell, rename, move, parentheses

I have the following PowerShell script that puts all .jpg files found in its subfolders into a 'Scans' folder and renames these .jpg files to match the name of their respective parent directory (=subfolder). When multiple .jpg files exist the renaming process will automatically add a number to the filename, like File_1,jpg and File_2.jpg.

So before the script is run a folder may look like this:

```
Parent Directory from which script is executed
       |
     Subfolder (containing .jpg files and the 'Scans' subfolder)
             |
             Scans (=folder)
             Photo.jpg
             Picture.jpg
             Shot(1).jpg
             Shot(2).jpg
```

Once the script has run the folder looks like this:

```
Parent Directory from which script is executed
       |
     Subfolder (containing the 'Scans' subfolder)
             |
             Scans (=folder containing supposed to contain all .jpg files)
                       |
                       Subfolder_1.jpg
                       Subfolder_2.jpg
                       Shot(1)       (=file moved but extension stripped)
             Shot(2)       (=file not moved and extension stripped)
```

So the .jpg files containing parenthesis 'Shot(1).jpg' and 'Shot(2).jpg' are not properly renamed and moved to the 'Scans' folder. In fact their '.jpg' extension is stripped off.

The script works fine as long as the .jpg files do not contain any parentheses (`()`), as in

- 'Shot(1).jpg' and 'Shot(2).jpg' → when multiple .jpg files exist
- 'Pics(2001).jpg' → when the subfolder name contains parentheses as in 'Pics(2001)', the .jpg is correctly renamed, but then contains parentheses and the script would fail again when run a second time.

I have read about escaping special characters in other threads but have not been able to implement a solution into the script below. Does anybody here have a solution so that the parentheses are not causing any issues when moving and renaming these .jpg files?

```
$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

function renamePhotos {
  # Loop through all directories
  $dirs = dir $path -Recurse | Where { $_.psIsContainer -eq $true }
  foreach ($dir In $dirs) {
    $i = 1
    $newdir = $dir.parent.name + "_"

    $images = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir.fullname -Filter *.jpg -Recurse
    foreach ($image In $images) {
      $split   = $image.name.split(".jpg")
      $replace = $split[0] -Replace $split[0],($newdir + $i + ".jpg")

      $image_string = $image.fullname.ToString().Trim()
      Rename-Item "$image_string" "$replace"
      $i++
      Move-Item -Path $dir\*.jpg -Destination $dir\Scans
    }
  }
}

# RUN SCRIPT
renamePhotos
"SCRIPT FINISHED"
```

Comment: why not just change the line to: `move-item -path $dir\*.jpg -destination $dir\Scans\*.jpg` as I think that will cover what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The `-replace` operator does a regular expression replacement. If you want to use it you need to escape special characters in your source string:

```
-replace [regex]::Escape($split[0]), "$newdir$i.jpg"
```

However, you don't need that in the first place. Simply use the appropriate properties of the `FileInfo` objects:

```
$images = Get-ChildItem -Path  $dir.fullname -Filter *.jpg -Recurse
foreach ($image in $images) {
  $newname = $newdir + $i + $image.Extension
  Rename-Item $image.FullName $newname
  $i++
}
Move-Item -Path $dir\*.jpg -Destination $dir\Scans
```

Or simply move the items to the new location with their new name without renaming them first:

```
$images = Get-ChildItem -Path  $dir.fullname -Filter *.jpg -Recurse
foreach ($image in $images) {
  $newname = $newdir + $i + $image.Extension
  Move-Item $image.FullName "$dir\Scans\$newname"
  $i++
}
```

Comment: Thank you for having resolved this! The Rename-Item works beautifully and can be run multiple times even when additional .jpg files with various naming conventions are being added to the folder. The Move-Item does not work as desired, because the files are then renamed to the upper Parent Directory instead of the name of the subfolder in which the .jpg files reside. @Leptonator the approach move-item -path $dir\*.jpg -destination $dir\Scans\*.jpg does not resolve the problem -- no change seen.